# Viewing contents of WAR file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to get Eclipse to recognize the WAR file extension as an archive type so that I can expand it and see the contents just like in a JAR.  How can I do that?

Comment: JARs are only expandable when set as a library on the Java Build Path of a Java Project.  Try creating a

Comment: In the Remote Systems Explorer, I can expand the contents of a JAR file. Why not a WAR file? Isn't there some way to simply add .war extension as a JAR file type? I constantly end up changing the extension from .war to .jar just to do this, but seems like there should be a way to avoid this.